# Why is this function computable in $O(n^{1.5})$ time?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, nondeterminism

My textbook says: "We define the function $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ as follows: $f(1)=2$ and $f(i+1)=2^{f(i)^{1.2}}$. Note that given $n$, we can easily find in $O(n^{1.5})$ time the number $i$ such that $n$ is sandwiched between $f(i)$ and $f(i+1)$."

How can I convince myself that we can in fact easily find $i$ in $O(n^{1.5})$ time? As $f$ is defined recursively, I think we have to compute $f(1),f(2),f(3)\dots f(j)$ until $f(j)\geq n$. In order to find out the time that these computations take, I think we have to find a suitable upper bound for $i$ dependent on $n$ and we have to find an upper bound on the execution time of the function $x\to2^{x^{1.2}}$. In the end, we can hopefully show the quoted proposition. Unfortunately, I don't see neither one thing nor the other.

I forgot to mention: Please note that we are in a nondeterministic context. So $f$ is claimed to be computable in $O(n^{1.5})$ by a nondeterministic Turing machine.

---

As quite a few people have already read this question, with some of them finding it useful and interesting too, but nobody answered so far, I want to provide some more information on the context: The quoted claim is an integral part of the proof of the nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem. The proof (with the claim) can be found e. g. in the [book by Arora and Barak](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/diagchap.pdf), but I have found quite a few other resources on the Web too which present the same proof. Each of those calls the claim easy or trivial and does not elaborate on how to find $i$ in $O(n^{1.5})$ time. So either all these resources just copied from Arora and Barak or the claim is in fact not so difficult.

Comment: This looks like the nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem proof in Arora & Barak, is it? If so, I assume nondeterminism plays a role here.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that, I should have mentioned the nondeterministic context. Can you please explain in more detail how nondeterminism helps us there to show the O(n^1.5) bound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote by $|x|$ the length of a number $x$, i.e. $\lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor + 1$ (for $x > 0$). Calculating $2^x$ requires time $O(x)$ in the RAM model, and so calculating $f(i+1)$ from $f(i)$ takes time $O(f(i)^{1.2}) = O(|f(i+1)|)$. Since $f(i)$ is growing faster than geometrically, the overall time to calculate $f(i+1)$ is $O(|f(i+1)|)$. As you point out, you need to do so until $f(i+1) \geq n$, which means that $f(i) < n$. Therefore the total running time is $O(|f(i+1)|) = O(f(i)^{1.2}) = O(n^{1.2})$.

In the Turing machine model with a single tape, calculating $2^x$ takes time $O(x\log x)$, and so the total running time is $O(n^{1.2} \log n) = O(n^{1.5})$. The algorithm for computing $2^x$ replaces $[x]$ by $1[[x]]$ (here $[x]$ is the binary representation of $x$, and $[[x]]$ is the binary representation using different digits $0',1'$), and then repeatedly runs the transformation $[[x]] \longrightarrow 0[[x-1]]$, which takes time $O(|x|) = O(\log x)$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! One more question: Don’t we have to argue that |f(i)| grows faster than geometrically rather than that f(i) grows faster than geometrically?

Comment: Since $|f(i+1)| = f(i)^{1.2}$, it's the same thing, but you're right. What we really want is $\sum_{j \leq i} |f(j)| = O(|f(i)|)$.